# Exporting queryset data using Django without have to re-query data

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, export-to-csv

I have set up a Django app that queries from a PostgreSQL database. Exporting all the data within a model seems relatively straight forward but what if I wanted to export only the data from a returned queryset.

Currently I'm managing this by having a button on my page and changing the url when the user wishes to export data. The code within the view that I'm rendering is as follows.

```
def export_data(request,pk):
    resource_class = MDPResource()
    queryset = MDP.objects.filter(mdp_id=pk)
    dataset = person_resource.export(queryset)
    response = HttpResponse(dataset.csv, content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="mdpbasic.csv"'
    return response
```

However, this means that I'm going to be making one query when the user initially opens the page and then a second query (in effect 2 extra) when the user wishes to export the data which I have already queried for in the previous view.

Moreover, in a section of my page I'm also using Q models for complex filtering. The above method is not sufficient for exporting data in that case (I don't want to have to reconstruct the query).

I also do not want to have to write the data to a file (if I can help it) because then that raises the issue of having to delete it using os once the user has exported their data.

[Generating CSV file with Django (dynamic content)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072574/generating-csv-file-with-django-dynamic-content)

I have already checked out this question but I'm not sure how passing a dictionary to a urlpattern works and it still seems as though the query is being made one more time anyways (still one less than my current method).

I don't know if I should be checking out apps for this particular purpose. I've looked into a couple such as django-queryset-csv and django-import-export but none of them seem to do what I've mentioned.

[django: export current queryset to csv by button click in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672477/django-export-current-queryset-to-csv-by-button-click-in-browser)

I've seen this example that makes use of class-based views but I wanted to see if there was a way to do it with function-based views so I don't have to migrate all my views to class-based ones.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is a problem. Each request is separate, so yes you will need to make a new query for the export page. Why does this concern you?

Comment: If the query is for a large amount of data which is going to take time to execute then I'm assuming it would be a problem? If this is the way everyone does it then I guess I could just go with it and see if there was a way to further refine my queries. It just seems unfortunate that I have to query the data again when I already have it available and the only new parameter is not something that will affect the data but a decision by the user to download the content.